# Why does my training loss oscillate while training the final layer of AlexNet with pre-trained weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am working on texture classification and based on previous works, I am trying to modify the final layer of AlexNET to have 20 classes, and train only that layer for my multi class classification problem.
I am using Tensorflow-GPU on an NVIDIA GTX 1080, Python3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.
I am using the Gradient Descent Optimiser and the class Estimator to build this. I am also using two dropout layers for regularization. Therefore, my hyper parameters are the learning rate, batch_size, and weight_decay. I have tried using batch_size of 50,100,200,weight_decays of 0.005 and 0.0005, and learning rates of 1e-3,1e-4,and 1e-5. All the training loss curves for the above values follow similar trends.

My training loss curve does not monotonically decrease and instead seems to oscillate. I have provided a tensorboard visualization for learning rate=1e-5, weight decay=0.0005, and batch_size=200.

Please assist in understanding what went wrong and how I could possibly rectify it.
[The Tensorboard Visualization for the case I specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiGWt.png)

```
  # Create the Estimator
  classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model)
  # Set up logging for predictions
  tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
  logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=10)
 # Train the model
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": train_data},y=train_labels,batch_size=batch_size,num_epochs=None,shuffle=True)
  classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200000, hooks=[logging_hook])
  # Evaluate the model and print results
  eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
x={"x": eval_data},
  y=eval_labels,
  num_epochs=1,
  shuffle=False)
  eval_results = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
  print(eval_results)

#Sections of the cnn_model
 #Output Config
 predictions = { "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),# Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
"probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")}  # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the `logging_hook`.
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

 # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
  onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels,tf.int32),depth=20)
  loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)


#Training Config
  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    tf.summary.scalar('training_loss',loss)
    summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=10,output_dir='outputs',summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op,training_hooks=[summary_hook])



# Evaluation Metric- Accuracy
eval_metric_ops = {"accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
print(time.time()-t)
tf.summary.scalar('eval_loss',loss)
ac=tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,predictions=predictions["classes"])
tf.summary.scalar('eval_accuracy',ac)
evaluation_hook= tf.train.SummarySaverHook(save_steps=10,output_dir='outputseval',summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())
return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops,evaluation_hooks=[evaluation_hook])
```

Comment: This question should go to: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RSSharma: Did you find the solution to your problem? I am facing a similar situation, my training loss also looks like a periodic function. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you selecting your mini-batches randomly? It looks like you have a high variance across your mini-batches which leads to a high variance of the loss at different iterations.
I assume the x-axis in your plot is iterations and not epochs and the training data provided every ~160 iterations is harder to predict which leads to the periodic drop in your loss curve. How does your validation loss behave?

Possible solutions/ideas:

- try randomizing your training data selection in a better way
- Check your training data for mislabeled examples

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Training data has been checked for mislabeling, and that is not the issue. My batches are selected randomly, wherein I have used Shuffle=True in the  train input function. How else can I try randomising train data selection?

CODE: train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": train_data},y=train_labels,batch_size=batch_size,num_epochs=None,shuffle=True)

Comment: It seems like you shuffle your data once and afterwards use the same shuffling in each epoch. If that is correct you can try reshuffling the data before each epoch. Then you shouldnt see the periodic drop in your loss. However, if there is a high variance across your training set than you will still not obtain a smooth curve. In general the higher the batch_size the smoother the loss curve. (Which does not mean that the training is faster)

Comment: Thanks. Will try the reshuffling part, and also increasing the batch size. And as the loss curve obtained using different optimizers follows different paths to the global minima, is there a case where an increase in loss followed by a descent is permitted? Or does the training loss have to decrease monotonically always?

Comment: Since such a network has usually lots of parameters you are dealing with a highdimensional objective function. This function usually is quite complex with lots of local minima and saddle points. Consequently it is hard to predict how the training will proceed and how the loss curve will look like. If you are coming out of a local minimum the loss can indeed increase and afterwards further decrease. Usually at some point of your training the loss will saturate.